# open a bootstrap 3.3.7 modal with angular 6 viewchild

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6

I have a bootstrap modal as follows in my component.html as follows

```
<div #myModall  class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am accessing it component.ts as follows.

```
 export class Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('myModall') myModall: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.myModall.nativeElement.modal('show');

  }
}
```

I have accessed it as per bootstrap 3.3.7 documentation in this link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals
Now i am getting an error as follows.
this.myModall.nativeElement.modal is not a function.
Any suggestions of how to access a modal from typescript file and to do it in a right way??????

Comment: can you have a working stackblitz link of the error as it should work

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkc7ix?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: where is the code that you have used ?

Comment: Sorry Rahul Singh I am not able add bootstrap references to stackblitz. Would u please add me and give me that link so that i could add my code. Sorry for the time delay.